# How share file public-ally in Internal Storage for another apps using android?

Tags: android, android-internal-storage, android-storage

I want to create a CSV file in my internal storage where other apps can access the file. The code I used is

```
public final static String fileName = "data.csv";
public final static String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS).getPath() + "/zfapp/";
```

Created above to variables in the class

```
new File(path).mkdir();
File file = new File(path , fileName);
if (!file.exists())
   file.createNewFile();
```

The above code was used to create the file when it was not there. This code worked for me when I used instead of the above.

```
public final static String path = Environment.getDataDirectory() + "/data/com.santechs.zfapp1/files/" ;
```

But I need to send this file as an email attachment using Gmail app, so I am not able to access the file as above line will create a file in private app folder not accessible by external apps.

Comment: And... What is the problem? And the question?

Comment: You should check the return value of mkdirs() and not continue if false.

Comment: You should only call mkdirs() if the directory does not exist yet.

Comment: with `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` I am not able to create the file, even the directory is not created. I think I have to use some other code there. I have tried many solutions found on net. But only `getDataDirectory()` created the file. But the file created using that is not accesible to gmail app.

Comment: You are not able to create that directory to begin with. And then you try to create a file in a directory that does not exist.

Comment: but when I assign path with `getDataDirectory()` its creating the file and directory

Comment: Yes i know. You already told twice. Pretty normal. Now first adapt your code so you realise that you cannot create that directory. No need talking about a file.

Comment: I got it fixed. it was not the problem of the path. From Nougat ownwards we had to use fileprovider [link]https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing[link] to share the file. That was were i made the problem.